# How to wake up from arch linux hibernation in virtualbox?

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, swap, hibernate

I accidentally placed my KDE arch linux virtualbox vm in hibernation - by this, I mean that I accidentally pressed the "hibernate" button in the SDDM lock screen. The screen just went black and nothing can be done - the VM did not actually shut down.

I do not have past snapshots available, but I do have the saved vm state right after hibernation. In such a case, can I wake up (or more correctly, "restore") my vm from hibernation?

I tried forced restart, which did not restore from hibernation. The VM does not respond to ACPI shutdown. Forcing a shutdown and booting again also did not restore from hibernation.

Kernel version is 6.2.8, I use X11, KDE Plasma is 5.27.3. 3GB memory is used, with 2GB swap partition. The main partition is 30GB, with a separate boot partition.

Comment: well, hibernation is meant for being woken up from. Have you tried that? It's literally nothing other than powering on the VM.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well, there are only few ways to "power up" in case the screen simply blackened out. I did try forcing a restart, which did not restore from hibernation. The VM does not respond to ACPI shutdown. I cannot think of other ways to reboot....

Comment: Now I'm confused. You say it's "in hibernation". That means shut down, powered off. A hibernated machine has stored its state to storage and powered off.

Comment: @MarcusMüller What happened was that after "hibernate" button in SDDM lock screen was accidentally pressed, the screen simply blackened out and did not actually shut down. So what I am thinking is that this is due to virtualbox not properly supporting the hibernation feature, and so possibly hibernation occurred, but the VM is not recognizing it. But I am not really sure what is going on.

Comment: there's nothing that virtualbox needs to support.